# How to change splash screen Ubuntu back?

Tags: plymouth

After installing kde plasma desktop on Ubuntu 15.10 splash screen changed when starting Linux to splash screen Kubuntu. How to change it back to Ubuntu splash screen.

Comment: Did you apply changes after installing plymouth?
if not type
<sudo update-initramfs -u>

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` in terminal.
2. Select the theme you want to apply.
3. Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` in terminal.